# Uncountably infinite dimensioned vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question

A countably infinite dimensioned vector space doesn't seem too far-fetched. An obvious basis exists and addition and scalar multiplication are trivial extensions.

Does an uncountably infinite (say, $\aleph_1$) dimensioned vector space make sense? Is it already a thing and, if so, what does it look like, how does it behave and what is it used for?

Comment: The reals make a vector space over the rationals, and has no countable basis.

Comment: Any infinite dimensional Hilbert space is a good example here.  The "separable" hilbert spaces have dimension $\aleph_1$, I think.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom [$\aleph_1$ is not necessarily $2^{\aleph_0}$!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis)

Comment: @NoahSchweber ugh, I always have it in my head that $\aleph_i := 2^{\aleph_{i-1}}$.  So those Hilbert spaces have dimension $\beth_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$, then...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yup, that's correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of such vector spaces:

- The space of all functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
- $\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.
- If $A$ is any set, the powerset $\mathcal{P}(A)$ of $A$ is a vector space over the field with two elements $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with vector addition given by "bitwise XOR."

But let me say a bit more about why we should expect such things, even without examples.

It's useful in this context to go back to the usual (= finite-dimensional) vector spaces and abstract a bit. We often think of a finite-dimensional vector space as a set of finite tuples - e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples of real numbers, and is the canonical $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. But a more abstract way to think of these vector spaces is as *maps*: "the canonical" $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (if you're familiar with fields, we can replace $\mathbb{R}$ with any field $k$) is the set of functions $f: \{1, 2, ..., n\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. This comes from thinking of a tuple as a function: a $3$-tuple of reals is a map $f$ from $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the idea being that the first element of the tuple is $f(1)$, the second is $f(2)$, and so forth.

With this in mind, we can now generalize to arbitrary sets. Given a set $X$, we can consider the set $Fn(X)$ of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (previously $X$ was $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ for some $n$, or more generally a finite set). It turns out that $Fn(X)$ is a vector space! Vector addition is given by $$f+g: x\mapsto f(x)+g(x),$$ and scalar multiplication is given by $$af: x\mapsto af(x).$$ If $X$ is uncountable, $Fn(X)$ an uncountable vector space. So by reframing the usual examples in a slightly more abstract way, we see that there's no obstacle to there being really big vector spaces!

*Actually the construction I've described above is often not the one we actually want; rather, we usually care more about the set $Fn_{fin}(X)$ of maps $X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with **finite support**, that is, which are equal to $0$ on all but finitely many elements of $X$. This doesn't make a difference when $X$ is finite, obviously, but makes a huge difference when $X$ is infinite: for example, $Fn_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ is countable-dimensional, but $Fn(\mathbb{N})$ is not. This is a good exercise; for one half, show that $Fn_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ can be thought of as the set of finite sequences of real numbers, and for the other half use a diagonal argument.*

Comment: Hi, I'm trying the exercise you suggested, but for $Fn(\mathbb{N})$ I am not sure how to apply the diagonal argument. I suppose that there is a countably infinite basis ($e_i$ where only the $i$th entry is 1 and the rest is 0) and try to show that I can find an element of the vector space not spanned by the countably infinite basis, but it's not obvious to me. If I may rephrase my confusion, you can have an uncountably infinite set which is a countably-dimensional (to me, the diagonal argument is useful for showing the uncountability of the set, but not for vector space dimension)

Comment: For me, the case of finite field $k$ is easier to understand. As a set, $Fn_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ is a countable union of countable sets so it is a countable set. Using the diagonal argument, $Fn(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountably infinite set. If the dimension of $Fn(\mathbb{N})$ were countably infinite, then it is isomorphic to $Fn_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ but it can't be true because the cardinality of the sets are different.

Answer (score 1):

For any cardinality $\alpha$ and any field $F$, there exists an $F$-vector space whose dimension is at least as big as that cardinality. To show this, let $X$ be any set such that $\vert X \vert = \alpha$. Then let $V = F^{X<\omega}$ (that is, the set of all functions from $X$ to $F$ with finite support). Given $u,v\in V$ and $c\in F$, define vector addition and scalar multiplication such that
$$(u+v)(x) = u(x)+v(x)$$
$$(c u)(x) = c(u(x))$$
holds for all $x\in X$. Then $V$ is a vector space.

For each $x\in X$, define $v_x$ to be the function which sends $x$ to $1$, and everything else to $0$. Then the set $\{v_x\, \vert \, x\in X\}$ is a basis of $V$ with cardinality equal to $\vert X \vert$, and so $\dim V \geq \vert X \vert$.

Answer (score 0):

An important example is the set of all continuous functions over the real numbers.